# Do the terminals of Sheremetyevo airport stay open over night?

Tags: airports, sleeping, moscow, svo

I realized that I bought a ticket that involves a 18-hour layover at Shremetyevo from afternoon to the next day morning. Do the terminals stay open overnight? If so, is it advisable to pass the night in the waiting area?

Comment: According to [sleepinginairports.net](http://www.sleepinginairports.net/europe/moscow.htm) it is open at night and actually sounds quite pleasant compared to others. However, I've never been there at night, so I can't tell from personal experience.

Comment: @neo Add a couple details and write down an answer before someone (aka me) swoops in and shamelessly steals it away from you. :)

Comment: Half-way confirmed.  I have been in Sheremetyevo-2 in the wee hours.  Sheremetyevo-1 shuts down after the last flight except for the private terminal, which is open 24/7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes I have heard from authorities of Shremetyevo airport that this airport remain open in night time and seems very pleasant during night also and you can enjoy your stay there. But I have no experience staying there.

Comment: This answer lacks authoritative references. Even more so since it's not based on detailed personal experience.

Comment: Which Sheremetyevo?

Comment: @GayotFow Sheremetyevo as in SVO